# $\frac{(-1)^n}{2\cdot 4\cdot \cdot\cdot2n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n\cdot n!}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, combinations

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\cdot 4\cdot \cdot\cdot2n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n\cdot n!}$$
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{3\cdot 5\cdot \cdot \cdot(2n+1)}=\frac{{(-2)^n} \cdot n! }{(2n+1)!}$$
can anyone tell me if these are true or false?

Comment: They seem both true to me.

Comment: Note that $$ 2^n n! = 2^n \cdot (1\cdot2\cdots n) = 2 \cdot 4 \cdots 2n$$ via distributing the $2^n$ into the $n!$.  The same holds for the second equality.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado no, $2^n \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdots n) \neq 2^n \cdot 2^{n+1} \cdots 2^{2n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are true.

For the first, note that

$$ 2 \cdot 4 \dots 2n = (1 \cdot 2) \cdot (2 \cdot 2) \cdot (3 \cdot 2) \cdot (4 \cdot 2) \dots (n \cdot 2) = n! \cdot 2^n$$

For the second:

$$3 \cdot 5 \dots (2n + 1) = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \dots (2n + 1)}{2 \cdot 4 \dots 2n} = \frac{(2n+1)!}{n! \cdot 2^n}$$

and

$$2^n \cdot (-1)^n = (-2)^n$$

Comment: and $(-2)^nn!=(-1)^n(2^n)n!$

Comment: @miniparser good, I'll add that to answer.

Comment: @lisyarus Sir I have a doubt. Kindly see this [image](http://i.imgur.com/yPpmBIG.jpg?1). I think that what I have done is also correct and your answer is also correct so where is the mistake? Kindly see that image and reply.

Comment: @Singh passing from 2nd to 3rd row: you have an error in moving 2 out of braces in the denominator. It should be $2^n$, not $2$.

Comment: Sir $2\cdot 4\cdot \dots 2n \ne 2(1\cdot 2\cdot \dots n)$ because this is not addition this is multiplication and so I'm wrong.